# R function to recode variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to recode countries into the Middle East and North Africa (MENA) region in R. Region is not a variable in the dataset but I want to clean my data up and code each country in a region.  How do I do this using the dplyr package?

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set along with the desired output. Also, there is a package available called "rworldmap" that provides this information in a dataset called `countryExData`.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil suggested, the data you want may already be curated in the {rworldmap} package. Here's some code to extract what it sounds like you're looking for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- rworldmap::countryExData[,2:4] %>% janitor::clean_names()

d %>% 
  filter(str_detect(epi_regions,pattern = "Middle")) %>% 
  mutate(continent = if_else(str_detect(geo_subregion, "Africa"), "Africa", "Middle East")) %>% 
  select(1, 4)
#>                             country   continent
#> 1              United Arab Emirates Middle East
#> 2                           Armenia Middle East
#> 3                            Cyprus Middle East
#> 4                           Algeria      Africa
#> 5                             Egypt      Africa
#> 6                              Iran Middle East
#> 7                              Iraq Middle East
#> 8                            Israel Middle East
#> 9                            Jordan Middle East
#> 10                           Kuwait Middle East
#> 11                          Lebanon Middle East
#> 12                          Morocco      Africa
#> 13                             Oman Middle East
#> 14                     Saudi Arabia Middle East
#> 15                            Sudan      Africa
#> 16                            Syria Middle East
#> 17                          Tunisia      Africa
#> 18                           Turkey Middle East
#> 19                            Yemen Middle East
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this manually, you can use `fct_collapse` from package `forcats`, this is explained in [this tutorial](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
dat %>%
  mutate(region = fct_collapse(country,
    MENA = c("Egypt", "Syria", "Lebanon")
  ))
```